# How to get number of CC libraries in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, extendscript

I am a beginner with InDesign scripting, trying to access libraries, but they appear to be not there.

My code so far:

```js
app.doScript(Main, undefined, undefined, UndoModes.ENTIRE_SCRIPT, "Run Script");

function Main() {
    app.scriptPreferences.userInteractionLevel = UserInteractionLevels.interactWithAll;

    var mydoc = app.documents.item(0);
    var lib_length = app.libraries.length; // not working
    var mypages = mydoc.pages.length; //works

    alert(lib_length, "\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I have 3 libraries, My Libraries, library1 and library2 with images in them. My code returns 0 libraries.

PS. Searching many files one by one in CC libraries with thousands of items is painful. I ultimately want to remake ImageCatalogFromList.jsx so it actually accepts a list(xlsx, csv) and place from CC libraries instead. It seems it is impossible to have scripts access and filter CC libraries. I may try menuActions but it also seems to have access only to the context menu.

Comment: If I have 3 libraries open your code will alert `3`. Do you have your libraries open? You say _"My code returns 0 libraries."_ what do you mean by that? Do you mean that it alerts `0` ?

Comment: Yes. It alerts 0. The libraries are sitting there in CC libraries, I don't know if they are open.

Comment: Open the libraries in InDesign before running your script  - then it should work.

Comment: Okay, if I create a local library, it counts. But it doesn't see my CC libraries.
[image](https://i.imgur.com/rNmEz9z.png)

Answer (score 0):

Libraries are .indl files which use to keep multiple library objects.
placed library objects are not getable by that line "app.libraries".
Because library objects are also text frames, rectangle frames, images or any other page items it can be.

If you open a library and run the code: app.libraries, then you will get number of library opened.

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fa8Ea.png)

Sunil

Comment: It works on libraries but not CC libraries which I am actually after.

Comment: InDesign Scripting DOM is outdated. CC libraries are added with newer version of InDesign. So Scripting will not work for CC libraries. Best practice for you is to ask this question on https://community.adobe.com/t5/InDesign/bd-p/indesign here will get better answer about InDesign Scripting.

Comment: I asked there but they can't help.
I have found this.
https://community.adobe.com/t5/InDesign/How-to-get-cloud-library-assets-placed-on-document/td-p/10114484
No documentation and no answers for now. It appears there is an upcoming API
"We'll be launching the CC Storage API in 2019. Sign up to get the launch announcement."
I hope it gets launched within the year and it can help with our problem.